# Preventing concurrency in a duplicated service

Tags: android, android-service

I'm using an IntentService to sync my SQLite database (managed by a Content Provider) with a webservice. My problem is that the service is triggered when the user refreshes the screen, hence there can be more of one service running at the same time. I'm afraid that might cause concurrency issues: data corruption for example.

My question is: Is there an "Android" way to prevent this to happen? Or do I have to build a queueing system myself? I know I could do put my whole service code in an atomic block, but I'm looking for something more elegant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IntentService` already handle for you a queueing system. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html):

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as
>   long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop),
>   but only one request will be processed at a time.

IMHO if you want a more robust and elegant solution to sync your `ContentProvider` with a webservice you should create a [SyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) which is much more powerful (it can even monitor your `ContentProvider` and trigger the webservice call).

Comment: thank you. I'm not using a syncAdapter basically because I'm just pulling data, not pushing anything.

Answer (score 1):

If the service is being triggered by Intents, then it will follow the normal lifecycle and the callbacks will get hit on the main UI thread of your app's process.  The service is not re-spawned with multiple instances.  If you spawn your own background thread or AsyncTask in the service to do some heavy lifting for you (i.e. process your data) then you'll need to protect things accordingly.